# How to install lua5.3 in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, software-installation, lua

I have started learning lua programming and have installed lua using below commands

> sudo apt install lua5.3 liblua5.3-dev

but when I do `$ lua`

I get this warning

```
Command 'lua' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install lua5.1
sudo apt install lua5.2
sudo apt install lua50
```

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/install-lua-in-centos-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: It looks like (unlike the lua5.1 and lua5.2 packages), lua5.3 does not automatically insert itself in the update-alternatives system - see for example [#863036 lua5.3 is not available in update-alternatives for lua(interpreter|compiler)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=863036)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commonly, when a distribution provides multiple versions (or multiple implementations) of a program, the `update-alternatives` mechanism is used to determine which one is run. This seems to be the case in general for `lua` ex. on my 18.04 box:

```
$ ls -l $(which lua)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Apr 17  2020 /usr/bin/lua -> /etc/alternatives/lua-interpreter

$ update-alternatives --query lua-interpreter
Name: lua-interpreter
Link: /usr/bin/lua
Slaves:
 lua-manual /usr/share/man/man1/lua.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/lua5.2
Value: /usr/bin/lua5.2

Alternative: /usr/bin/lua5.2
Priority: 120
Slaves:
 lua-manual /usr/share/man/man1/lua5.2.1.gz
```

In the case of `lua5.3` it seems that the new alternative does not get added by the package - see for example [Debian Bug report logs - #863036
lua5.3 is not available in update-alternatives for lua(interpreter|compiler)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=863036)

You can add the version manually (choosing a suitably higher priority if you want it to be the default) ex.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/lua lua-interpreter /usr/bin/lua5.3 130 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/lua.1.gz lua-manual /usr/share/man/man1/lua5.3.1.gz
```

after which you should see

```
$ lua -v
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

You will probably want to do the same for `lua-compiler`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/luac lua-compiler /usr/bin/luac5.3 130 \
  --slave /usr/share/man/man1/luac.1.gz lua-compiler-manual /usr/share/man/man1/luac5.3.1.gz
```